# Saving a data set in a txt file using C

Tags: c, dataset, save

I have an array `double x[D] = {x0,y0,z0;x1,y1,z1;...;xn-1,yn-1,zn-1}` which describes the positions of n particles in a system. `D` is the number of particles times the spatial dimension which, in this case, is 3. I have 500 particles so D=1500. Integrating yields a new array for every new time step. So what I am doing is something like this

```
int maxiter = 3000;
FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3;
fp1 = fopen("position_data.txt", "w");
fp2 = fopen("velocity_data.txt", "w");
fp3 = fopen("force_data.txt", "w");
initialize(x, v, f, ptr_pot, ptr_kin, timestep, 150, 5);
for (i = 0; i < maxiter; i++) {
    integrate(x, v, f, ptr_pot, ptr_kin, timestep);
    for (j = 0; j < D; j++) {
        fprintf(fp1, "%.6f\t", x[j]);
        fprintf(fp2, "%.6f\t", v[j]);
        fprintf(fp3, "%.6f\t", f[j]);
    }
    fprintf(fp1, "\n");
    fprintf(fp2, "\n");
    fprintf(fp3, "\n");
}
fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);
fclose(fp3);
```

It works fine for a few particles, but for many particles the txt file is a mess. The first link is messed up, whereas the second for n=50 particles is not. Any idea what is going wrong? Thanks.

```
 46.418646 160.081780  190.209660  72.701186   147.917129  130.295733  130.851150  70.735792   172.411264  165.434727  6.213581    182.360317  184.136498  11.157569   64.186527   109.347805  41.523464   100.894175  78.420365   8.923597    138.224432  157.695225  67.726691   160.692167  127.347618  46.522410   64.272000   87.032686   85.177172   108.175918  36.799218   8.343763    70.558786   106.045705  175.280010  14.227714   136.252950  17.108663   43.018888   31.995587   148.490842  198.248232  2.728373    173.638093  70.986068   159.172338  22.565378   142.612984  69.655456   73.366511   68.532365   81.606505   94.253369   58.046210   189.489426  142.588576  93.264554   154.557940  100.943028  160.368653  118.240932  40.400405   173.973829  110.910374  73.781551   4.205460    35.389269   135.697500  169.554736  14.752630   85.610524   13.299947   30.426935   15.436269   140.220344  59.559913   121.176786  75.386823   101.712077  137.394320  41.737128   128.434092  67.506954   157.780706  149.559013  131.260091  180.565833  152.867219  65.065443   171.898538  28.815586   102.688663  116.617329  159.910890  99.703970   196.606335  81.142601   29.419823   95.992935   110.776081  76.766274   86.349054   19.220537   182.885203  163.591426  30.933572   26.941744   65.364533   108.963299  87.008268   170.043025  138.474701  73.445828   169.078653  16.406753   64.253677   73.732721   118.588804  67.171231   162.858991  178.734689  140.592668  171.764275  192.364280  95.193351   72.005369   48.036132   13.324392   98.934911   12.793350   113.773006  119.406740  168.102070  151.292477  135.703606  115.189064  74.568926   114.908299  102.395705  122.562351  89.864820   77.480407   27.198097   196.881001  61.708442   154.515198  87.551512   134.086111  117.593923  117.545091  6.793402    150.157188  151.499974  158.940402  84.908615   14.008006   150.114460  138.279377  184.252441  115.231806  114.706881  41.669960   76.662484   47.767566   35.010853   85.207659   58.143863   190.935983  71.242409   193.768107  37.324136   68.880286   0.646979    86.501645   4.101698    169.878238  84.694950   100.228899  84.493538   6.579778    13.226719   181.890320  88.143555   98.593082   81.856744   181.475254  154.637275  58.497883   58.772547   76.534329   4.882963    62.709432   97.262474   59.657600   3.863630    88.290033   150.206006  119.980462  140.891753  197.088534  42.719814   50.166343   133.750436  48.323015   59.340198   110.019226  162.913907  120.999795  1.831131    77.956483   42.054512   27.295761   173.967725  121.628467  131.192986  198.266543  49.537652   18.976396   198.565627  122.952961  79.812008   160.863064  137.717813  22.412793   196.649069  66.615785   145.811324  139.658795  67.629007   43.751317   69.539494   126.859332  59.352384   123.044545  124.912248  111.130090  165.202815  100.234996  97.030541   120.017091  53.785813   15.662111   26.306939   48.048323   94.381554   103.030501  87.154775   45.496976   115.530855  138.511321  65.572069   110.733342  153.123551  21.570479   141.782888  167.253643  144.163337  118.637673  184.191395  6.793439    22.492155   0.903347    60.939348   179.711280  172.765279  107.553335  175.310525  13.788248   98.751803   165.587314  131.113639  42.957870   62.489681   97.585995   134.556096  26.874594   150.315861  48.591585   38.514368   42.890703   122.074042  63.350313   35.798207   31.464576   99.850459   45.240624   107.364120  76.369505   52.345364   128.086203  31.940660   0.891145    131.260098  92.074354   63.185539   161.357460  15.802502   155.107260  80.697054   19.061863   121.750526  170.775460  121.079125  172.099978  31.110570   164.207909  95.358129   28.095325   198.840285  37.079994   198.986800  199.285876  92.648094   173.046072  20.606102   1.019325    22.376182   174.694036  55.995345   135.166496  15.009022   63.551745   33.259083   139.384136  191.625716  174.144734  155.626107  83.755005   2.594062    73.378717   68.080706   95.925787   177.227086  136.753454  54.072690   195.965443  144.083977  112.247082  68.544583   22.266302   178.283029  103.512662  113.534959  129.752508  31.989489   103.372276  162.627034  41.511261   104.367180  108.993800  140.464482  135.294674  107.199327  149.906916  163.579225  145.939505  82.546457   60.243549   148.850968  165.129542  128.495141  126.285595  195.715201  119.638644  89.443643   40.705598   48.512225   9.326466    167.070517  94.680611   45.167410   86.190360   108.230850  39.130849   58.388019   55.641336   126.090275  146.391175  35.737177   81.307416   10.687578   103.469948  44.788972   74.648278   185.216832  68.239398   29.590763   50.489806   164.232305  119.766831  184.704136  29.932554   170.110176  33.985401   153.086928  71.681875   163.914925  16.095449   154.057445  113.217579  46.992397   120.749548  47.553960   2.923682    89.510792   191.467015  41.016876   4.535034    142.185744  50.379946   45.063621   155.040125  87.502689   169.695133  184.270740  157.390041  86.599307   155.912942  69.234274   189.233063  78.127386   78.340994   136.283460  108.883933  85.299236   172.905652  60.957652   39.802235   187.414153  152.610854  151.603766  14.905247   112.039539  55.922112   129.258102  61.781660   104.202404  64.259775   0.134278    10.278633   28.754544   19.891947   26.990556   3.558443    162.193671  75.484491   105.429251  193.908499  30.152283   6.512637    151.701396  4.583893    146.946612  17.853312   7.934808    38.935500   13.184010   175.701158  71.333976   17.999813   27.954935   96.200435   153.325009  27.918339   71.620854   21.930599   175.090809  58.302545   15.637703   117.526776  5.725272    112.955108  115.549187  115.707885  49.134786   73.995169   143.400369  144.920205  86.056090   0.854530    15.930653   69.917916   177.422388  45.234520   174.645223  176.445804  135.264129  63.313688   74.123364   131.296748  167.467274  106.521805  34.803312   49.061570   2.612388    72.035874   16.412835   196.758936  101.126148  94.314390   168.401140  167.534390  58.998395   158.903780  113.541067  54.866173   10.376312   119.717991  21.021156   58.314765   135.184783  1.141396    25.220497   52.217153   78.096880   166.118354  46.418667   148.490873  185.100864  31.476780   169.731726  184.850611  163.853889  111.850328  38.483828   169.646293  74.141665   73.274930   18.341623   14.618384   54.676964   177.861888  188.311421  186.785467  92.428364   0.701916    114.969348  10.663147   40.839861   0.335686    66.200770   52.253774   193.090601  23.908203   20.587789   115.768921  16.657020   128.403575  128.739275  84.633931   155.552830  199.139391  182.854697  137.778877  106.247157  146.739111  150.761438  172.643192  73.812076   163.921001  130.588708  166.008492  14.300977   23.249012   182.457973  104.037594  169.737850  97.207559   193.322532  12.640785   101.913524  81.734692   31.330298   119.547108  131.315031  104.562537  145.817443  79.171124   187.304305  199.536119  69.289242   91.750828   175.957508  28.254048   177.617721  47.749265   71.645236   30.170591   164.653448  129.001745  38.782933   82.485436   187.566748  197.643965  189.825113  51.039173   139.158301  4.303120    85.891304   113.498334  3.332620    146.598700  186.211723  36.024050   150.047294  9.271512    152.635267  84.743811   125.962085  17.285671   15.460662   153.190712  197.045806  32.984399   106.912448  187.047935  199.383529  28.687385   168.309563  87.404995   154.423666  65.919972   137.461474  173.760198  4.950096    112.503422  22.296816   188.042847  128.012927  128.849163  167.113260  120.908215  180.999194  154.557933  117.612232  41.572328   137.247823  26.746415   191.088608  12.360011   67.317740   61.207912   157.835629  69.295343   122.202213  127.713867  140.269170  149.974041  74.752049   50.746184   135.734114  149.931321  75.588237   166.850780  69.508969   188.763083  179.674676  169.823313  184.051012  67.299401   99.832131   75.173178   70.870064   197.033602  143.540751  34.821607   151.249743  183.007279  189.074392  33.552054   111.948000  141.563154  57.435826   198.297052  102.352986  134.037289  136.210198  151.579329  199.121083  197.753836  11.590912   140.354627  144.676046  155.485683  164.922016  171.483511  65.828411   84.762111   89.895309   85.079520   178.630932  28.131952   86.709180   197.045817  185.894353  25.696592   89.455872   41.926343   173.497743  51.179553   182.921855  47.498998   111.764904  132.749401  165.123462  72.151846   168.205823  39.851051   11.780160   36.457392   137.803268  17.334526   199.017318  180.169064  197.137359  148.063613  140.440060  175.768293  88.583042   25.293729   95.046855   29.993580   140.861231  116.092409  1.965392    4.461816    32.142092   97.006144   198.480188  86.672561   101.974531  143.229476  77.425468   42.670997   118.308043  52.565098   40.412620   182.628863  105.838208  185.412151  2.868744    70.485561   141.923262  101.950119  7.373276    109.097562  126.358829  77.913739   1.403843    31.897940   31.171618   180.132438  135.807366  32.557161   36.811423   82.992021   40.186767   163.707408  60.847824   107.284752  31.586646   136.094232  85.573899   62.508018   112.485111  149.388114  190.618630  173.924997  114.615307  85.824149   96.932905   75.655382   44.685202   98.055978   128.330349  151.048294  188.299200  122.324289  196.862693  1.532028    28.345583   148.332159  118.271443  125.296773  134.092223  176.989044  63.789800   186.877046  77.205709   97.262500   54.469445   159.129618  131.034268  13.476954   104.409935  118.649871  9.241012    54.213077   118.973373  175.969739  0.274660    194.109910  154.435866  121.762754  153.678988  119.797353  145.103314  70.339055   74.636051   71.254627   104.379425  81.661413   183.019512  89.761044   105.771057  43.061598   193.078397  3.765993    50.355528   192.059084  70.094920   183.904534  126.743360  161.375769  20.282586   198.370293  169.866038  127.518533  170.091842  199.981692  24.909210   144.096208  91.195413   176.073496  122.525719  41.157243   27.546027   92.593148   171.605593  171.807012  180.498657  63.557842   175.927006  187.298206  108.444475  177.129445  80.837421   121.964178  197.192296  109.622476  56.337163   169.096976  57.185575   158.641331  122.623362  29.102437   4.095580    26.557207   124.564336  11.224691   78.664525   185.753961  161.217088  169.963669  162.419491  156.566048  76.656409   57.533487   45.258969   129.581610  118.424017  173.644198  1.245149    63.148904   169.743962  93.679627   128.897996  87.636933   61.879336   156.773590  12.091415   147.538687  172.789680  94.790494   158.067552  112.723165  18.335527   83.663425   168.443862  90.090633   42.378016   198.156688  99.862649   166.856894  111.911392  151.463366  170.250540  116.702770  123.508411  100.820967  67.006458   100.143438  27.399507   0.311306    13.495282   90.194388   75.344106   82.302327   49.879445   54.725792   198.559515  148.509156  84.731604   26.734219   122.031310  52.204975   173.558763  93.673495   121.359915  52.632236   180.565809  37.250906   28.449335   22.907176   79.830335   54.860065   192.291044  192.754908  52.229387   93.832214   1.019311    7.190179    34.253987   29.914255   71.639149   182.543426  75.112145   21.106615   113.473928  140.910048  158.177415  68.105111   171.776463  104.446564  43.256919   112.698761  57.618958   30.640570   185.741734  105.240034  70.400098   69.856880   88.943148   172.588272  19.141189   126.371060  145.957809  117.593906  48.878430   4.229865    127.164529  181.560698  78.389844   119.083209  169.713431  100.784346  155.485684  57.283260   25.189977   188.561651  136.136982  163.499849  21.790212   73.714425   193.688788  38.123715   97.109917   27.149278   164.372693  125.663013  157.951615  107.443481  35.438090   75.417349   123.325279  56.886494   182.091726  55.647453   106.888047  179.125358  59.468382   102.548278  95.101782   129.734193  156.053354  85.183274   177.324728  50.880460   114.529846  167.754129  84.115117   181.463062  26.581621   150.315852  90.005202   173.747997  7.702887    169.304493  36.951800   48.066641   58.357475   139.072850  134.763618  16.534943   117.703806  15.655984   94.680640   107.187120  116.165665  64.119396   52.504031   19.769896   133.091218  10.596021   37.330224   144.456312  65.688059   60.408354   42.292561   174.602498  115.622426  63.411346   53.474528   44.978182   99.319418   7.843267    93.325619   26.654886   88.497580   124.021121  34.717865   109.689646  186.895352  178.923932  42.005678   105.032493  149.650547  43.159294   195.263508  196.783357  51.496922   111.404761  153.965877  176.122309  110.019221  57.539601   16.418948   88.094720   70.253628   105.960250  31.080043   122.562333  56.849883   99.972553   116.147330  80.532245   100.094593  148.844868  43.519401   47.138909   41.950747   134.543893  43.574346   2.490326    28.528718   59.523299   86.770241   1.684625    95.004133   116.769903  198.553408  55.207984   49.458301   63.362518   63.655521   140.977187  161.796921  178.777427  76.149774   79.238256   63.924089   189.257468  91.396820   101.657151  167.571043  39.399401   36.231579   45.789957   5.902281    92.294091   33.613076   6.140318    5.243066    39.393289   197.949173  173.198633  93.093662   101.431314  157.377850  91.512813   48.731938   1.568646    59.273051   68.269907   2.679513    92.117088   115.219566  163.426600  191.204566  115.945901  41.578414   92.745737   172.148808  183.977780  52.186633   75.026713   8.368162    49.903853   159.099095  154.661686  25.006873   63.448000   37.861261   30.860317   46.778758   83.358269   13.501400   124.784072  121.646781  131.455432  23.401610   115.768925  37.067773   68.898599   113.431208  77.993088   35.041355   76.039898   123.545035  48.774683   32.270275   16.956093   119.003894  159.721663  151.609868  70.058297   23.657957   162.053282  71.102006   105.954178  11.352904   77.315607   196.911530  193.798623  111.801516  4.742565    166.209899  117.459650  187.182208  16.479977   86.501644   82.644123   135.685278  171.965714  17.468778   96.346922   78.255560   182.683812  101.669379  199.755864  184.777384  158.616901  50.288407   35.956899   95.968524   167.516103  190.246274  133.689391  197.277765  38.355660   178.862894  188.256494  100.863655  140.165400  192.358149  121.085232  192.181153  167.491703  94.442592   198.968480  197.143471  63.771497   191.222895  194.317433  26.300842   113.858467  78.664528   67.744972   52.223272   136.863305  188.940090  154.118478  76.302386   10.748619   141.789010  133.353689  141.282373  59.736939   107.254263  167.290280  45.728930   135.843973  85.982841   83.773301   116.733316  125.882758  113.351849  189.312423  97.024462   115.042588  93.643009   191.412083  102.810749  138.389236  70.625919   12.012068   108.584866  151.463370  40.620140   173.192560  115.085289  151.341275  114.474931  136.259024  56.776622   79.268790   134.543884  75.789653   4.980630    36.231561   153.068628  69.545559   122.983497  42.634340   78.078567   185.729556  129.331359  73.378717   93.142494   48.707560   125.601958  199.609378  157.219165  164.561914  144.871354  168.297362  190.777307  187.560676  77.108080   51.033047   54.560982   9.015157    127.823743  93.148605   127.152314  49.543766   66.090875   194.488350  187.597263  36.164427   18.372156   153.117459  9.375294    45.387124   64.241457   103.115958  171.984021  93.569730   190.264578  77.816089   96.237052   55.781715   58.424618   129.618203  9.814760    194.451718  145.237601  137.736124  48.982218   79.000218   107.712037  135.093219  2.948081    177.806948  132.663965  85.580009   107.101649  103.592035  125.376149  142.973098  191.228998  193.633852  94.009207   122.727130  189.129293  5.999950    185.955369  17.926583   115.793328  13.019179   132.389311  90.621653   118.387406  73.268831   157.274094  169.780592  107.364135  163.347272  107.083340  87.173082   173.815130  150.645449  57.466338   82.381667   99.514744   88.406037   153.105242  108.169808  165.703305  14.264341   137.034223  67.549669   166.972878  133.597827  125.681334  113.681437  36.500156   168.822303  85.836373   43.952751   188.854640  156.041124  169.823285  119.455560  186.596275  70.168158   165.153980  141.044358  37.000653   159.782690  14.838119   113.351832  125.089266  173.052171  64.711429   127.921365  89.223929   155.900754  193.877971  196.722329  45.576327   3.692749    84.701079   67.293333   67.604620   47.694316   188.439602  150.822470  126.938684  57.515194   42.829657   194.329680  1.763964    140.842938  97.927801   28.229614   159.111300  121.720021  106.332606  20.593876   117.148354  78.530237   34.174624   169.243438  93.862734   23.017062   149.015796  62.971887   48.298606   1.623584    40.968057   43.263030   120.609142  0.244162    33.277364   197.527985  177.178251  133.848091  138.584537  115.262300  67.134612   102.023396  17.151389   38.428924   96.371349   191.894268  93.313378   137.119655  125.437186  9.418004    86.336877   141.898868  197.460878  20.612213   112.015150  64.064472   102.462850  83.614631   11.212480   35.041338   184.215810  53.169329   61.616852   196.099721  195.916622  38.532670   128.897990  69.814146   110.953085  196.191284  13.660069   144.352568  95.022430   38.526552   50.251769   101.901321  145.768626  139.896834  113.846245  22.528775   6.317321    21.015065   91.927860   194.640962  58.833597   93.307280   176.537354  63.313706   4.437398    44.135877   33.387245   147.886585  35.682238   144.376984  4.303097    59.755255   107.876820  59.431765   198.968489  51.985220   15.472884   45.118561   32.471688   31.690418   79.793690   109.463779  64.833512   66.621914   154.301583  21.814633   98.629722   117.136136  153.770566  150.498988  191.125235  24.756634   13.446439   10.138249   137.156275  88.711199   84.615614   100.149532  78.872018   61.519230   72.676776   115.323342  198.773165  95.034641   124.124887  110.055859  
46.418645   160.081779  190.209659  72.701185   147.917132  130.295734  130.851148  70.735790   172.411264  165.434725  6.213583    182.360319  184.136501  11.157569   64.186527   109.347802  41.523461   100.894172  78.420366   8.923594    138.224432  157.695222  67.726693   160.692168  127.347615  46.522409   64.272003   87.032686   85.177173   108.175919  36.799218   8.343763    70.558785   106.045704  175.280010  14.227712   136.252952  17.108661   43.018888   31.995584   148.490839  198.248231  2.728375    173.638090  70.986071   159.172337  22.565377   142.612983  69.655458   73.366513   68.532366   81.606506   94.253370   58.046211   189.489426  142.588575  93.264553   154.557940  100.943029  160.368651  118.240935  40.400405   173.973831  110.910375  73.781551   4.205461    35.389270   135.697500  169.554737  14.752627   85.610524   13.299944   30.426932   15.436270   140.220344  59.559912   121.176785  75.386823   101.712075  137.394319  41.737130   128.434092  67.506956   157.780708  149.559013  131.260088  180.565836  152.867220  65.065440   171.898535  28.815587   102.688660  116.617329  159.910891  99.703970   196.606334  81.142599   29.419820   95.992937   110.776080  76.766276   86.349052   19.220534   182.885201  163.591427  30.933574   26.941745   65.364532   108.963301  87.008268   170.043024  138.474704  73.445826   169.078654  16.406753   64.253678   73.732721   118.588801  67.171230   162.858994  178.734687  140.592668  171.764276  192.364282  95.193354   72.005368   48.036132   13.324393   98.934912   12.793348   113.773007  119.406743  168.102072  151.292480  135.703606  115.189064  74.568926   114.908301  102.395705  122.562353  89.864822   77.480409   27.198097   196.881000  61.708444   154.515196  87.551514   134.086109  117.593923  117.545090  6.793400    150.157191  151.499972  158.940403  84.908618   14.008008   150.114463  138.279378  184.252440  115.231809  114.706883  41.669958   76.662482   47.767565   35.010856   85.207656   58.143863   190.935980  71.242409   193.768105  37.324136   68.880287   0.646977    86.501643   4.101699    169.878239  84.694947   100.228900  84.493537   6.579777    13.226718   181.890321  88.143554   98.593080   81.856743   181.475252  154.637273  58.497883   58.772547   76.534330   4.882963    62.709431   97.262471   59.657602   3.863628    88.290031   150.206007  119.980461  140.891753  197.088534  42.719814   50.166346   133.750438  48.323016   59.340200   110.019226  162.913907  120.999796  1.831134    77.956483   42.054513   27.295761   173.967727  121.628467  131.192989  198.266543  49.537653   18.976394   198.565626  122.952959  79.812008   160.863064  137.717811  22.412793   196.649070  66.615783   145.811322  139.658794  67.629006   43.751315   69.539496   126.859330  59.352382   123.044548  124.912246  111.130089  165.202818  100.234996  97.030540   120.017091  53.785812   15.662113   26.306937   48.048321   94.381556   103.030504  87.154778   45.496973   115.530852  138.511323  65.572069   110.733339  153.123548  21.570479   141.782888  167.253643  144.163337  118.637675  184.191393  6.793441    22.492157   0.903347    60.939347   179.711278  172.765278  107.553336  175.310525  13.788246   98.751804   165.587312  131.113642  42.957873   62.489678   97.585997   134.556094  26.874594   150.315860  48.591587   38.514369   42.890701   122.074042  63.350312   35.798206   31.464575   99.850458   45.240622   107.364121  76.369504   52.345366   128.086205  31.940658   0.891146    131.260097  92.074355   63.185542   161.357459  15.802505   155.107258  80.697055   19.061863   121.750524  170.775458  121.079124  172.099977  31.110570   164.207912  95.358128   28.095323   198.840283  37.079994   198.986802  199.285878  92.648094   173.046075  20.606103   1.019326    22.376184   174.694034  55.995343   135.166499  15.009025   63.551745   33.259084   139.384135  191.625715  174.144737  155.626110  83.755006   2.594060    73.378719   68.080709   95.925788   177.227086  136.753456  54.072689   195.965442  144.083976  112.247083  68.544585   22.266301   178.283029  103.512660  113.534959  129.752510  31.989487   103.372273  162.627034  41.511258   104.367177  108.993799  140.464481  135.294676  107.199328  149.906915  163.579227  145.939504  82.546456   60.243551   148.850967  165.129541  128.495143  126.285595  195.715201  119.638642  89.443642   40.705599   48.512226   9.326467    167.070515  94.680609   45.167413   86.190357   108.230851  39.130851   58.388020   55.641335   126.090276  146.391174  35.737177   81.307416   10.687578   103.469947  44.788973   74.648279   185.216832  68.239399   29.590765   50.489804   164.232305  119.766830  184.704138  29.932554   170.110177  33.985399   153.086925  71.681875   163.914926  16.095447   154.057446  113.217581  46.992397   120.749550  47.553963   2.923684    89.510793   191.467014  41.016876   4.535032    142.185745  50.379945   45.063619   155.040124  87.502691   169.695134  184.270737  157.390038  86.599304   155.912940  69.234271   189.233063  78.127387   78.340991   136.283461  108.883933  85.299236   172.905650  60.957649   39.802234   187.414151  152.610854  151.603769  14.905248   112.039537  55.922111   129.258103  61.781658   104.202404  64.259775   0.134278    10.278633   28.754544   19.891944   26.990554   3.558441    162.193671  75.484492   105.429252  193.908498  30.152282   6.512635    151.701395  4.583895    146.946611  17.853310   7.934808    38.935498   13.184012   175.701158  71.333978   17.999812   27.954933   96.200433   153.325012  27.918340   71.620857   21.930599   175.090812  58.302542   15.637706   117.526776  5.725272    112.955108  115.549188  115.707886  49.134784   73.995168   143.400368  144.920207  86.056090   0.854532    15.930651   69.917918   177.422386  45.234518   174.645223  176.445802  135.264127  63.313686   74.123365   131.296751  167.467275  106.521805  34.803312   49.061572   2.612389    72.035871   16.412832   196.758937  101.126151  94.314388   168.401141  167.534387  58.998397   158.903781  113.541068  54.866172   10.376314   119.717989  21.021157   58.314765   135.184782  1.141397    25.220498   52.217150   78.096882   166.118355  46.418669   148.490875  185.100864  31.476778   169.731724  184.850611  163.853890  111.850327  38.483826   169.646293  74.141665   73.274929   18.341623   14.618386   54.676964   177.861890  188.311423  186.785464  92.428365   0.701915    114.969351  10.663144   40.839860   0.335683    66.200773   52.253771   193.090600  23.908203   20.587790   115.768922  16.657023   128.403575  128.739274  84.633931   155.552828  199.139393  182.854697  137.778880  106.247159  146.739113  150.761438  172.643189  73.812077   163.920999  130.588709  166.008494  14.300977   23.249014   182.457975  104.037593  169.737850  97.207559   193.322530  12.640788   101.913526  81.734695   31.330298   119.547108  131.315030  104.562540  145.817444  79.171125   187.304305  199.536119  69.289244   91.750825   175.957506  28.254050   177.617720  47.749266   71.645233   30.170589   164.653446  129.001746  38.782934   82.485438   187.566746  197.643964  189.825110  51.039176   139.158301  4.303121    85.891305   113.498334  3.332620    146.598698  186.211721  36.024051   150.047293  9.271511    152.635266  84.743813   125.962083  17.285669   15.460660   153.190712  197.045805  32.984398   106.912449  187.047933  199.383529  28.687383   168.309560  87.404993   154.423667  65.919970   137.461474  173.760200  4.950096    112.503420  22.296815   188.042847  128.012925  128.849166  167.113260  120.908212  180.999196  154.557932  117.612232  41.572330   137.247820  26.746414   191.088610  12.360014   67.317742   61.207911   157.835629  69.295346   122.202212  127.713868  140.269169  149.974038  74.752050   50.746185   135.734113  149.931319  75.588236   166.850777  69.508971   188.763083  179.674677  169.823316  184.051009  67.299399   99.832129   75.173176   70.870061   197.033602  143.540750  34.821605   151.249745  183.007277  189.074395  33.552054   111.948001  141.563153  57.435824   198.297050  102.352987  134.037289  136.210196  151.579328  199.121086  197.753835  11.590910   140.354627  144.676046  155.485680  164.922015  171.483512  65.828408   84.762112   89.895307   85.079522   178.630930  28.131950   86.709178   197.045818  185.894355  25.696593   89.455875   41.926345   173.497745  51.179555   182.921856  47.498997   111.764907  132.749399  165.123464  72.151844   168.205824  39.851048   11.780163   36.457389   137.803267  17.334528   199.017320  180.169062  197.137358  148.063615  140.440057  175.768292  88.583044   25.293727   95.046856   29.993578   140.861231  116.092408  1.965392    4.461817    32.142091   97.006145   198.480189  86.672560   101.974529  143.229477  77.425469   42.671000   118.308042  52.565100   40.412621   182.628863  105.838210  185.412151  2.868745    70.485562   141.923260  101.950117  7.373276    109.097562  126.358828  77.913737   1.403842    31.897940   31.171620   180.132437  135.807366  32.557163   36.811423   82.992019   40.186766   163.707411  60.847827   107.284749  31.586644   136.094230  85.573899   62.508019   112.485110  149.388115  190.618633  173.924998  114.615306  85.824148   96.932907   75.655381   44.685202   98.055980   128.330351  151.048292  188.299200  122.324289  196.862693  1.532028    28.345582   148.332159  118.271445  125.296770  134.092223  176.989044  63.789801   186.877047  77.205707   97.262501   54.469447   159.129619  131.034267  13.476951   104.409937  118.649873  9.241013    54.213076   118.973376  175.969741  0.274659    194.109907  154.435866  121.762755  153.678985  119.797353  145.103315  70.339055   74.636049   71.254629   104.379427  81.661410   183.019514  89.761045   105.771059  43.061595   193.078396  3.765994    50.355526   192.059084  70.094921   183.904533  126.743358  161.375768  20.282584   198.370290  169.866040  127.518532  170.091839  199.981692  24.909210   144.096211  91.195414   176.073497  122.525720  41.157240   27.546030   92.593147   171.605595  171.807014  180.498654  63.557841   175.927007  187.298208  108.444475  177.129448  80.837420   121.964179  197.192296  109.622475  56.337162   169.096979  57.185574   158.641333  122.623361  29.102435   4.095579    26.557207   124.564334  11.224689   78.664528   185.753961  161.217089  169.963666  162.419489  156.566047  76.656412   57.533486   45.258972   129.581613  118.424015  173.644195  1.245148    63.148905   169.743964  93.679629   128.897999  87.636931   61.879337   156.773591  12.091412   147.538687  172.789678  94.790495   158.067549  112.723165  18.335528   83.663422   168.443862  90.090632   42.378018   198.156689  99.862646   166.856893  111.911395  151.463367  170.250537  116.702768  123.508411  100.820970  67.006460   100.143438  27.399505   0.311308    13.495282   90.194386   75.344107   82.302329   49.879444   54.725793   198.559513  148.509154  84.731606   26.734219   122.031309  52.204977   173.558763  93.673493   121.359917  52.632238   180.565809  37.250908   28.449332   22.907174   79.830337   54.860064   192.291047  192.754908  52.229389   93.832215   1.019310    7.190182    34.253988   29.914257   71.639149   182.543428  75.112143   21.106617   113.473929  140.910046  158.177413  68.105111   171.776460  104.446566  43.256917   112.698763  57.618960   30.640568   185.741731  105.240035  70.400098   69.856881   88.943148   172.588272  19.141186   126.371063  145.957807  117.593904  48.878428   4.229865    127.164530  181.560695  78.389844   119.083207  169.713431  100.784349  155.485682  57.283263   25.189976   188.561650  136.136984  163.499847  21.790212   73.714428   193.688790  38.123715   97.109920   27.149280   164.372693  125.663013  157.951618  107.443484  35.438090   75.417350   123.325276  56.886493   182.091724  55.647453
```

Comment: Show textual information as text please.

Comment: What exactly is a mess about the list of numbers your picture shows. I don't see it.

Comment: see the new link

Comment: Ok, sorry that I have not been precise enough, please provide textual information in text shape and directly here, instead of linking or showing a picture of text.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "provide textual information in text shape"

Comment: I don't recommend using the tab character.  I recommend writing everything line by line.

Comment: Your links are links to pictures of text. The rest of your question is text. Please show your examples as text by copying text into the question. Do not link, do not make pictures. Formatting can be done for you, surely some user will help you with it.

Comment: @FragiadoulakisAggelos: do not insert images or screen dumps, insert the text of the output inside a code block (between <pre> and </pre> tags) in the question itself

Comment: @user3121023  Nope, it doesn't work

Comment: @chqrlie but why is that?

Comment: @FragiadoulakisAggelos: so people can cut the text from the question and examine it  on their machine, for example one cannot distinguish spaces and TABs on images.

Comment: @chqrlie Ok, this makes sense now. There are lots of things that are assumed to be known in IT community which I am not aware of. Thanks

Comment: @FragiadoulakisAggelos: welcome to the world of knowledge and experience: Learn something new everyday and  enjoy the ride!

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in the second file are >= 10 and < 100, hence they all have the same number of characters when converted to text with `%.6f`, so the TAB characters convert to the same number of spaces, aligning text on 8 character columns.

The first file has numbers that convert to different widths and the terminal seems confused when handling very long lines that wrap on a tab character.

The problem is not in the file produced, but rather in how it is displayed by your terminal.

To avoid relying on how the output device handles TAB characters, you can use spaces for alignment and not use TAB characters at all. For example, if you know all numbers to have a magnitude < 1000, you could use:

```
 fprintf(fp1, " %11.6f", x[j]);
```